How can I whitelist a URL with no user agent in my .htaccess?
I work at a web design agency (Wordpress), and all of our websites link back to our own site credits in the footer. However, our security plugin adds a line in the .htaccess file that blocks all requests that do not specify a user agent in order to prevent bots with a 403 error like this:
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
This is fine for the sites we still manage, as we simply added a user agent into the request. However we have some ex-clients that we don't host or manage anymore, and those requests are being blocked because they have no user agent and we have no way of adding one anymore. Is there a way I can add something to our .htaccess that whitelists these URLs so they can make the request without a user agent?
I've tried adding various http headers and a few other things (it's been a while I can't remember), but nothing worked.

"... that blocks all requests that do not specify a user agent in order to prevent bots ..." ... What bots should get blocked by that? I am not really aware of a bot that does not specify a user agent, though it obviously might be a forged one ...

How exactly would you be "adding" a User-Agent to the request my browser makes, when I click on a simple link ...? Are you perhaps confusing User-Agent with Referer here?

Here is the list of bots that the line in .htaccess supposedly blocks http://pastebin.com/u/hackrepair, its why we can't get rid of the line. And I don't know, that's why I'm asking if it's possible.
